# Facebook Apps permission language

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are creating a Facebook apps which require the posting right to the user wall, however in the permission panel the right asked and their details is written in english, as we target french user we would need to change the language of the permission window.

I know we can't enter the text ourself (as it would allow to write anything else than what the right is about), but is there a way to indicate the language in which the permission should be written?

Example : When the user see my permission panel it is written : "Post on your behalf", and once he accept it, he can see in his application setting that he gave the right to "Publier en mon nom". This mean Facebook actually has that translation, but how do I show it to the user AS THEY accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work by default, although perhaps you are using the older version of the Permissions Dialog. This should be based on the language locale of the user and doesn't require any intervention from the developer:

[image: French GDP]